# Ruby - every nth iteration

Tags: ruby

How would I print "Hello" every nth of an iteration in ruby using something like:

```
50.times do
  # every nth say hello
end
```

Comment: @DaveNewton care to show an example with that being used?

Comment: @Zenph I added an answer showing `%` operator in use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think `times` will work for that case. But you can iterate over range instead:

```
(1..50).each do |i|
  # print hello if number of iteration is multiple of five
  puts 'Hello' if i % 5 == 0
  # do other stuff
end
```

**Updated** (thanks to *d11wtq*)

It turned out that [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) yields iteration number to the block too:

```
50.times do |i|
  # print hello if number of iteration is multiple of five
  puts 'Hello' if (i + 1) % 5 == 0
  # do other stuff
end
```

Numeration is zero-based so we add 1 to iteration number (you can use `i % 5 == 4` instead, but it looks less obvious).

Comment: `times` yields the iteration index into the block too.

Comment: Oh my, thank you @d11wtq, you opened my eyes. For some reason I always though it doesn't and used ranges iteration for that.

Comment: I see people making that assumption often :)

Comment: I spend a lot of time in docs lately to learn new stuff. But when I started with ruby I got a lot of knowledge from code examples. I've never seen `times` passing iteration number to block, so I though it doesn't do that. Shame on me.

Comment: alternatively, ActiveSupport provides `i.multiple_of? 5` if you're on rails. Looks nicer i think, i wonder why it is not part of core ?

Answer (score 11):

```
(0..10).step(2) do |it| 
  puts it
end
```

Outputs:

```
0
2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: doesn't that skip other iterations? I am trying to do this without skipping any iterations, just performing an extra action on the nth iteration. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It skips other iterations. Update your question to include this remark.

Comment: @Yossi I think it's implied in the question via the `50.times` part that it'll iterate 50 times, and print every `nth`.